# Why does a batch file executed from a WinRAR SFX not work on accessing hosts file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command, winrar, sfx

This batch code works on running the batch file directly:

```
set %windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
attrib -r %hosts%
pause
```

But it does not work as expected on packing this batch file into a WinRAR self-extracting archive and running it automatically during extraction.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. What does this have to do with WinRAR, and what do you mean by "not working">

Comment: This code working :                                                                               
 ((( set hosts="%windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts"
attrib -r %hosts%
( 
echo 127.0.0.1 example1. com
echo 127.0.0.1 example2. com
) >> "%hosts%"
pause  )))

but if i create 'winrar self extracting archive'-so 'exe' not working batch file 'command'

Comment: That didn't really clarify anything. You can't use self-extracting archives to turn batch files into exe files; archives are just containers.

Comment: Update your question with additional code.  Do not put it in comments.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a 32-bit RAR self-extracting archive. Therefore the batch file is processed by 32-bit `cmd.exe` which results in accessing `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` instead of `%SystemRoot%\System32` according to Microsoft's [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) documentation. You should also take a look on [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details) and [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/shared-registry-keys).

The directory `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` does not contain `drivers\etc\hosts`. The `hosts` file exists on 64-bit Windows only in subdirectory of `System32` for 64-bit applications.

`Sysnative` redirector existing only for 32-bit applications running on 64-bit Windows can be used to determine in which environment the batch file is running to access the `hosts` file which usually only malware modifies, but no friendly application installed with a RAR self-extracting archive.

```
@echo off
set "SystemPath=%SystemRoot%\System32"
if exist "%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\cmd.exe" set "SystemPath=%SystemRoot%\Sysnative"
set "HostsFile=%SystemPath%\drivers\etc\hosts"
%SystemPath%\attrib.exe -r %HostsFile%
pause
```

Please note that `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative` is neither a directory nor a link in file system. It is a redirector for 32-bit applications on 64-bit Windows. So with 64-bit Windows Explorer as started by default on 64-bit Windows or any other 64-bit application `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative` does not exist at all. And 32-bit applications can only check if there is any file in `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative`, but can't check if a *directory* `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative` exists.